# Natual Language processing patent by Oracle

Tags: patent-infringement, copyright, oracle

Oracle holds a Patent US20130103391 "Natural language processing for software commands". I didn't exactly understand what they actually claim. Anyway, If I publish an ERP program that has a search box where user can enter some question regarding the analysis of the data like - 'what will be the sale next day?', and if the applications responds by giving a set of results regarding the question, will it be considerer as an infringement of the above patent?

Also, If yes, then why Apple's Siri is not a patent infringement even it has the same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, that application has not yet issued as a patent.  You can look at http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair to find the status of most applications.

Second, you're conflating copyright and patent infringement.  This is a patent question, and I don't see an implication of copyright law.

Finally, the essence of your question is a good one.  The claims that issue, if the application does issue as a patent, may be different from those in the original application.